# Sending Google Analytics event from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

I have a web app that is a single page with an iframe. Page and iframe are from the same origin. I'm trying to send an event to google analytics from within an iframe like this:

```
if(typeof parent.ga !== 'undefined') parent.ga('send','event', Category, Action, Label );
```

I also tried this approach:

```
if(typeof parent.ga !== 'undefined') parent.sendGaEvent(Category, Action, Label);
```

And in the parent the function looks like this:

```
function sendGaEvent(Category, Action, Label){
   ga('send','event', Category, Action, Label);
}
```

None of those approaches seem to work. The events don't show up in Google Analytics. However if I send an event like above from the parent of the iframe it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve parent to child communication here. If the iframe is on another domain and you have control over it then you can use Cross-domain post messaging.
Please go through the link http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: upon receiving the message the iframe can then send a hit to the google server.

Comment: Why do I need Cross-domain messaging? The iframe just displays another .html from the same server. Does this count as another domain?

Comment: No that does not mean cross domain is the origin (domain) and protocol matches (http / https) then you can simply send an event to the iframe that initiates the google analytics call . Go through the example here http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe-iframe.php

Comment: thanks for this answer. do you know why events can't be tracked from iframes on the same domain? is this still the case in 2020?